# Deploying with Capistrano... file not found (Asset pipeline)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, asset-pipeline

When trying to deploy with Capistrano I am getting a ton of these errors:

[err :: localhost] tar: 20120220182722/app/assets/images/assets/Thumbs.db: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Every asset I have can't be found and capistrano errors out (doing a deploy:cold)

I've uncommented this line in the capfile:

```
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
```

but it still says the same thing.

The above line is actually in my Capfile here is the rest of my deploy.rb (note that I am using vagrant and trying to deploy to a VM created with vagrant)

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :application, "testdeploy"
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "."

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`
server "localhost", :app, :db, :primary => true
ssh_options[:port] = 2222
ssh_options[:keys] = "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@testdeploy/gems/vagrant-0.9.4/keys/vagrant"

set :user, "vagrant"
set :group, "vagrant"
set :deploy_to, "/var/testdeploy"
set :use_sudo, true

set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_strategy, :export

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Comment: What does the rest of your `deploy.rb` look like?